# Why use conjugate not transpose complex conjugate in superoperator？

Tags: pauli-gates, depolarizing-channel

For the n-qubit depolarizing noise, I want to know why it uses $\sigma_{0}^{i*}$ instead of $\sigma_{0}^{i}$ or $\sigma_{0}^{i\dagger}$.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just the standard way that you write down the superoperator. Think about the following:

If I have
$$
\rho\mapsto \sigma\rho \sigma^\dagger
$$
then if I want to write this as a superoperator, I start with
$$
\rho=\sum_{ij}\rho_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|
$$
and rewrite it as a vector
$$
|\rho\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\rho_{i,j}|i,j\rangle.
$$
The the superoperator is the matrix $M$ such that
$$
M|\rho\rangle=|\sigma\rho \sigma^\dagger\rangle.
$$
Thus, $M$ is written
$$
M=\sum_{i,j,k,l}M_{ij,kl}|i,j\rangle\langle k,l|.
$$
We have
$$
\sum_{kl}M_{ij,kl}\langle k,l|\rho\rangle=\langle i,j|\sigma\rho\sigma^\dagger\rangle=\langle i|\sigma\rho\sigma^\dagger|j\rangle.
$$
Hence,
$$
M_{ij,kl}=\langle i|\sigma|k\rangle\langle l|\sigma^\dagger|j\rangle.
$$
Now, transpose the second term,
$$
M_{ij,kl}=\langle i|\sigma|k\rangle\langle j|\sigma^\star|l\rangle.
$$
You can verify that this is the same as
$$
=\langle i,j|\sigma\otimes \sigma^\star|k,l\rangle.
$$
(If in doubt, work backwards!)
Thus,
$$
M=\sigma\otimes\sigma^\star,
$$
as required.

Comment: $M_{ij,kl}=\langle i|\sigma|j\rangle\langle l|\sigma^\dagger|j\rangle$ should be $M_{ij,kl}=\langle i|\sigma|k\rangle\langle j|\sigma^\dagger|l\rangle$ ? And can you tell me why $M_{ij,kl}=\langle i|\sigma|j\rangle\langle l|\sigma^\dagger|j\rangle =\langle i,j|\sigma\otimes\sigma^*|k,l\rangle$ ?

Comment: Sorry, my indices got a bit jumbled in the middle there! Should be correct now, and hopefully a little clearer as a result.